# A way to time change of text in TextView?

Tags: java, android

I need to change the text of a TextView the moment an other activity is started but not fast enough so the user can see it before the activity is changed, so it stays there and waits until back button is pressed and the user is returned to the previous activity.

```
recordBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(isRecording) {
                    isRecording = false;
                    recordLabel.setText("Do it again!");
                    stopRecording();
                    startActivity(new Intent(AudioRecorder.this, VoiceChanger.class));
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(!isRecording) {
                    isRecording = true;
                    recordLabel.setText("Recording...");
                    startRecording();
                }
                break;

        }
        return false;

    }
});
```

The default text from XML is "Tap the mic and record".
While the user is recording audio it is changed as "Recording..."
When the user stops recording the next activity loads automatically, at this stage the recordLabel should be blank.
After the activity transition is complete (some milliseconds) the text should be changed as "Do it again!".

At the current state the "Do it again!" text appears the moment recording is stopped, but the user is being moved to the next activity and is not able to record unless they go back, which is awkward for them to see.

Comment: Please take a look at existing answers and upvote/downvote/accept/comment according to whether they answer your question in a helpful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the label text and then launching the new activity with `startActivity()`, launch the new activity with `startActivityForResult()`, and change the label text in the `onActivityResult()` callback of the caller activity.

See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result for details on using 
`startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`.